# Transparent Polyline

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

This is my first question here so sorry if I get something wrong.

I am trying to draw a polyline in Google Maps but the specified color for the polyline seems not to accept the alpha channel of the color. The line is always solid.
How could be this achieved? or is it possible at all?

I am doing this with Xamarin.iOS and the google maps control for the Xamarin.iOS but a solution in Objective C and Google Maps SDK for iOS would be great too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I found a solution to the problem, but it is a semi-solution because not every color can be reproduced.

I used full green to draw a line and the alpha channel did not seem to have any effect.
When I used a line with RBG color (0,0,10) it seems to create a line that is semi transparent and green.

So to me it looks like that the RBG color channels are actually combined the color and the transparency (or they are implemented so that the color channel is just transparency channel for the full color).

Comment: This issue looks like it might be related: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5342

Comment: This issue seems to be solved in the latest google maps library (1.8.1) and now the polyline accepts the alpha channel when started on the device. For the simulator this answer still applies.

Answer (score 0):

Did you only run it on the simulator or on the device as well? From my testings it appears that there's a bug in the simulator that makes all polylines opaque, but the alpha channel works on the device.

Comment: I ran it both on the simulator and on iPhone 3GS and on iPhone 4S and it seems that the alpha channel does not have any effect.